# Users Page Search option shows first page after searching instead of previous page

Tags: discussion, feature-request, search

I've seen an issue in Stack Overflow's user search option.

I navigated to page 55 using the page number option displayed below on the "Users" page, then I get a page like:

> [image: Actual page]

Then I searched for a person from there, I got the result so I cleared the search box.
At that time the it showed the first page instead of 55th, but the URL was of the 55th page.

Why does it always show the first page after every search? It would be better if it showed the previous page (here 55th page) instead of first page.

> [image: Issue]

Answer (score 1):

Think about your exact case, filtered *very* few combinations (other than the word "user") would even have a 55th page.  It's more intuitive to show it from the first page than a page that is likely blank, especially since we prioritize *exact* matches above partial ones.  Having different behaviors when adding or clearing from the search box is also non-intuitive.

What we *should* do is change the URL with HTML5 history here, something we'd do a lot more if it weren't for a certain insanely entrenched and outdated browser pool that hails from Redmond.  Given that, we have to include a plugin for these pages to behave the same across browsers - is it worth it here?  [Even IE9 doesn't support HTML5 history methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3722815/does-internet-explorer-support-pushstate-and-replacestate) (...seriously?).

Maybe we should just say "screw it" and < IE10 gets a different, lesser experience.  I'll bring it up on our team call Tuesday, but I'd put decent money on that being our answer.  Including a decent chunk of JavaScript to support (effectively) *only* IE at this point is a little crazy.